# Text Suggestions Popup

Tags: android, textview, spell-checking, android-input-method

I am implementing a text editor (not using TextView or EditText components) and when a word is misspelled I would like to bring up a popup similar to what TextViews have after you tap on the word.  Is this UI the TextView brings up available in the android framework to use or will I have to create my own custom UI for this?

I can't seem to find anything after searching through the documentation.  All I can find is a spell checker framework which just tells you if a word is misspelled and gives you an array of suggestions.  Is there something in the input method service that might provide this UI?

Edit: I also need the "Add To Dictionary" option in the context menu so the user can add new words to the user dictionary. Similar to how TextView does it.

Comment: autocompletetextview with a custom filter.

Comment: But that's still a TextView. Not using the android TextView classes to display text at all in my app.

Comment: it seems that all you have to do is show an alert with you array of word. I don't know what specific ui component you would be expecting.

Comment: I thought there may have been something in the input method framework that handles this. I wanted the exact component TextView uses.  An alert dialog I think is only modal(?) and makes the entire screen behind it darker so I lose context to the word that is being referenced.  The UI needs to be positioned so I can see the word.  I'm guessing I will have to create my own ListPopupWindow for this.

Comment: I assume you read http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/creating-input-method.html#IMEAPI already?

Comment: Yes, looked through it.  Nothing stood out when looking at the various classes there.

Comment: apparently you are supposed to provided the `candidates` view. And there is an example

Comment: Saw that, but that candidates view is a custom view. Thanks for checking that out though, I might use that as a base for what I want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't implemented it myself yet, but it looks like using a [ListPopupWindow](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListPopupWindow.html) will work. It also interacts with IME if you wish and anchors itself to a parent view.